# FFTW fftwf_plan_r2r_2d() with FFTW_REDFT01 equivalent

Tags: opencv, fftw, dft, dct, kissfft

I am trying to port code that uses FFTW to use KissFFT.
The code uses [`fftwf_plan_r2r_2d()` with `FFTW_REDFT01`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html#Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029).

What would be the equivalent call in KissFFT?

If this call (with `FFTW_REDFT01`) is equivalent to a DCT, could I just use a direct DCT transform instead, e.g. such as [OpenCV `cv::dct`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=dft#dct)?
Is there some input data modification I'd need to do, like reflections and symmetrizations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question...
With the help of [these](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/126307) [two](http://www.dsprelated.com/showmessage/93988/1.php) references, I ended up *not* using DFT at all, but using OpenCV's `cv::dct()` and `cv::idct()` instead.

To answer the question, `fftwf_plan_r2r_2d(...,FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_REDFT10,...)` can be replaced by this OpenCV code with the additional scaling:

```
cv::dct(img, resFFT); // fwd dct. This is like Matlab's dct2()
resFFT *= (4 * sqrt(float(img.rows/2)) * sqrt(float(img.cols/2)));
resFFT.row(0) *= sqrt(2.f);
resFFT.col(0) *= sqrt(2.f);
```

The inverse with `FFTW_REDFT01` can be done like so:

```
// First re-scale the data for idct():
resFFT /= (4 * sqrt(float(img.rows/2)) * sqrt(float(img.cols/2)));
resFFT.row(0) /= sqrt(2.f);
resFFT.col(0) /= sqrt(2.f);
cv::idct(resFFT, outImg); // this will return the input exactly

// However, the transforms computed by FFTW are unnormalized, exactly like the corresponding, 
// so computing a transform followed by its inverse yields the original array scaled by N, where N is the logical DFT size. 
// The logical DFT size: Logical N=2*n for each axis, this is th implicit symmetrization
// of the image: reflect right and then reflect both halves down.
int logicalSizeN = (2*img.rows) * (2*img.cols);
outImg *= logicalSizeN; // scale to be like FFTW result
```

More helpful links [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029.html#Real-even_002fodd-DFTs-_0028cosine_002fsine-transforms_0029) and [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002dto_002dReal-Transform-Kinds.html#Real_002dto_002dReal-Transform-Kinds).

Note that OpenCV supports only images with an even number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I recently stumbled on this exact problem, I also need to port a function fftwf_plan_r2r_2d(..., ..., ..., ...,
        FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT))) Any ideas?